# Official Daily PPA for Unity?

Tags: unity, ppa, testing

I found couple of blocker bugs in Unity which came installed in 12.10 and swtiched to GNOME Shell.

Is there official ppa for Unity to check if developers fixed the bugs already?

Comment: Can't you subscribe to these bugs at Launchpad?

Comment: @vasa1 "Fix committed" issue status doesn't mean it's been tested already. :)

Comment: Please bring back Unity PPA for 18.04, if that is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is meant by "official ppa" in the question, but here are some links from Launchpad.

[Unity staging ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Eunity-team/+archive/staging)

> This archive contains the latest builds generated from trunk, that
> have passed the unit tests, but didn't pass the user acceptance
> (autopilot) tests yet.   Unless you are a developer and know what you
> do here, you should probably use the "unity-team/ppa" instead.

---

[Unity PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eunity-team/+archive/ppa)

> This archive contains various testing packages, especially ARM builds.

---

[Unity SRU channel](https://launchpad.net/%7Eunity-team/+archive/sru)

> This PPA contains proposed package builds for our next Stable Release
> Update versions of the Unity stack components.

---

Note that ppas typically are described as "untrusted".

Comment: The unity staging PPA is closed, you should use the unity daily ppa instead: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-unity/+archive/daily-build